# minimum date of the year

Tags: asp.net

I have one text box and i have to show minimum date of the current year in that texbox

that means:
suppose consider if i select current_time (09/11/2009)
then(01/01/2009) should be shown in text box

awaiting ur response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
As Noldorin points out, the simplest and most terse solution is something like this:

```
var firstDayOfYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);
```

**My old answer:**

This should do it.

```
var now = DateTime.Now
var firstDayOfYear = now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(now.DayOfYear - 1)).Date
```

Edit:
Actually this would be a bit cleaner:

```
var today = DateTime.Today
var firstDayOfYear = today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(today.DayOfYear - 1))
```

Comment: .Today would probably be better than .Now and that actually do sums is unnecessary - just create a new date?

Comment: Yeah, I use today in my edit, you're right about that. There's no functional difference in creating a new date time and summing. I guess it's a matter of personal taste in this instance. But I voted Noldorins answer up so I agree it's a good way of doing it too.

Comment: There is a bug here: it gets the last day of the previous year (e.g., on the 1/1/2009 it's day 1, reducing 1 will take it to 31/12/2008)

Comment: @Patrik - I was thinking in terms of efficiency/work (ultimately that sum has to create a new DateTime) and also clarity of intent.

Comment: @Elisha - Thanks for pointing that out, I edited to fix this.

Comment: Ugh! This solution is dreadfully inelegant. Someone please tell me why this has been accepted.

Comment: @Noldorin: Though I'm the author of this "dreadfully inelegant" code I'm pretty much with you. I answered this a bit to quickly and I have actually voted your answer up and I think that should be the accepted one. However I don't think this is all that dreadfull, as I think it's a bit more semantically "telling".

Answer (score 10):

You just want to construct a new `DateTime` with the same year, and other parameters set to one (for first day and month).

```
var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now; // or whatever else
var firstDayOfYear = new DateTime(currentDateTime.Year, 1, 1);
```

Comment: I'd suggest: new DateTime(DateTime.Today, 1, 1); as being slightly nicer (and assuming we're talking server side).

Comment: @Murph: You mean `DateTime.Today.Year`? I don't really see the advantage in that, though of course it works just as well. I think we must be talking server-side here, with the tag being `asp.net`.

Comment: Yes, meant .year - and you're right that in context there's not a lot of difference between .Now and .Today - except that if you're thinking in terms of dates rather than date/time I think its better to use Today because your intent is more obvious. As for assuming its server side - it assumes that the tag is right, I develop asp.net sites and from time to time I have client side javascript problem in my asp.net sites... long, long ago we were taught never to assume when programming - I probably go too far sometimes but not without reason (from experience)

Comment: Yeah, I guess we'll have to wait and see. If it's AJAX though, the problem can be solved on server-side regardless. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had to solve this same problem in the past. In the end, I decided to create an Extension Methods class for the DateTime class to encapsulate and test the albeit simple functionality.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime GetFirstDayOfYear(this DateTime date)
    {
        return new DateTime(date.Year, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Now all I would have to do to get the date required is

```
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.Today;
DateTime firstDayOfYear = selectedDate.GetFirstDayOfYear();
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you can get a DateTime object from the textbox (e.g. DateTime.Parse(...)) you can do this:

```
DateTime inputDate = DateTime.Parse(textBox.Text);
DateTime outputDate = new DateTime(inputDate.Year, 1, 1);
```

Comment: This will throw an exception, since 0 is an invalid month/day.

Comment: Is 0 a valid value for month and day in DateTime constructor? I didn't know this.